# multiple RTPs in vxworks

Tags: c++, embedded, vxworks

I am a newbie in vxworks. I want to create multiple RTPs. Is there any example related to that? I know how to create tasks but I want to learn how to handle communication among these RTPS

Comment: This question doesnt show any research effort. You should start by reading the manuals.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is, of course.

You can spawn many RTPs using as many `rtpSpawn` calls as you wish. These can be many instances of the same RTP binary, or may be different binaries.

These can also be started by providing a list in the `script` field of the boot parameters, or from the shell.

Inside your RTP, you can also spawn multiple tasks.